# Faker and Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker

I'm trying to figure out if someone knows a way to perform this task. I am wanting to try and tell how many of each type of role to have for the users inserted. That way I can have it say I only want 1 other of role number 4 and 2 of role number 3 and have the rest be one. I'm sure there's going to be some additional logic but not sure how something like this should be written.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        // use the factory to create a Faker\Generator instance
        $faker = Faker::create();

        $roleIds = App\Role::lists('id');

        User::create([
            'first_name' => 'Me',
            'last_name' => 'Me',
            'username' => 'me',
            'email' => 'me@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'active' => 1,
            'role_id' => 1
        ]);

        foreach(range(2, 100) as $index) {

            User::create([
                'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
                'username' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->userName),
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => $faker->word,
                'active' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 90),
                'role_id' => $faker->randomElement($roleIds)
            ]);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try to use different foreach's for specific number of role_id's and fix the id in each foreach based on what you need.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        // use the factory to create a Faker\Generator instance
        $faker = Faker::create();

        $roleIds = App\Role::lists('id');

        User::create([
            'first_name' => 'Me',
            'last_name' => 'Me',
            'username' => 'me',
            'email' => 'me@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'active' => 1,
            'role_id' => 1
        ]);

        foreach(range(1, 2) as $index) {

            User::create([
                'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
                'username' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->userName),
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => $faker->word,
                'active' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 90),
                'role_id' => 1
            ]);
        }

        foreach(range(1, 3) as $index) {

            User::create([
                'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
                'username' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->userName),
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => $faker->word,
                'active' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 90),
                'role_id' => 2
            ]);
        }

        foreach(range(2, 100) as $index) {

            User::create([
                'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
                'username' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->userName),
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => $faker->word,
                'active' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 90),
                'role_id' => rand(3,5)
            ]);
        }

    }

}
```